# Changing the name of a button

Tags: vb.net, button

So I am trying to make a validation where, for example,

if the user drop into a button a file and it already exists into the database it will displays a message("This file already exists") and it should rename the button name from the name of the file onto the actual name of it.

This is the method that I am calling at the moment of dropping a file into a button and it will change and display what I want.

```
Private Sub UpdateControls()
        SQLCon = New SqlConnection
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = "........."

        Dim query As String
        query = "SELECT Filename 
                FROM infofile
                WHERE Filename=@Filename"

        If cmdEntrar.Text = query Then
            cmdEntrar.Text = "Open file"
        Else
            cmdEntrar.Text = MeuFicheiro.Name
            cmdEntrar.Width = GetButtonSize(MeuFicheiro.Name)

            lblArraste.Left = cmdEntrar.Left + cmdEntrar.Width + 15
        End If
    End Sub
```

Because I have a `Public Sub` where I've called it AddFile and there I will add a bunch of things from a file(name, extension, etc) into my database. But if I add a file that already exists it will clear all the labels from layout and change the name of the button to the original. But that part is not working.

This is the piece of code where the validation is made

```
 Public Sub AddFile(Filename As String, Filetype As String, Filesize As String, Created As Date, Modified As Date, Access As Date, PcName As String)
    SQLCon = New SqlConnection
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MIGG-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TrashCollection\TrashCollection\TrashDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
    Try
        Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO INFOFILE (Filename,Filetype,Filesize,Created,Modified,Access,PcName) " &
                                  "VALUES (" &
                                  "'" & Filename & "'," &
                                  "'" & Filetype & "'," &
                                  "'" & Filesize & "'," &
                                  "'" & Access & "'," &
                                  "'" & Created & "'," &
                                  "'" & Modified & "'," &
                                  "'" & PcName & "')"
        SQLCon.Open()
        SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(strInsert, SQLCon)

        SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Ficheiro existente!")
        pathTextBox.Clear()
        lblName.Text = String.Empty
        lblType.Text = String.Empty
        lblSize.Text = String.Empty
        lblCreated.Text = String.Empty
        lblModify.Text = String.Empty
        lblAccess.Text = String.Empty
        lblKB.Text = String.Empty
        nomePcLbl.Text = String.Empty
        pbIcon.Image = Nothing
        pbGreenDot.Image = Nothing
        pbRedDot.Image = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

And I want to add in this exception the possibility to change the button text to the original one

Any solution for That? Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

You should be manipulating the `page load` where the controls text are cleared.

> Would be more useful if you share the code.

Comment: I kinda understand what this is doing. After I insert a file and the "This file already exists" message displays it will clean all labels and it should change the button text too. This button is used to after insert a file I can open it through the button. It should change the text too :S

Comment: Firstly you shouldn't handle these in the catch part. You could use a seperate sub to clear the defaults or load from other source. and check the label text during postbacks.

Comment: I've made some tests and break points and I found an error called - "Value of type Boolean()" cannot be converted to 'Button'. " Do you have any idea  what it should be?

Comment: I've just solved my problem. It was hard to find the problem but finally I was able to do it. Thank you for your tips!